Scoring system to predict ordinal grades
I am currently working on a medical research project. We are trying to make a scoring system to predict difficulty of surgical operation.  We collected data (around 150 operations) with preoperative variables and graded difficulty (grade 1,2 and 3) of operations.  We did ordinal regression analysis (both univariate and multivariate) and found 3 variables (binomial, binomial and ordinal variables) that were significant for graded difficulty.
We managed to make a system with weighted scores for each variables and predict binomial difficulty (1 and 2 as easy and 3 as difficult) but we would rather want to make a system to predict ordinal grades (1,2 and 3).
Is there any suggestion so we can make scoring system to predict ordinal difficulties grade (1,2 and 3) from 3 variable? Thank you for help in advance!

Ordinal regression should have given you what you want. What about it did not? Are you sure you did ordinal regression??

And the double dipping you engaged in when you selected variables using supervised learning can ruin everything else.
